# Combine multiple temp SQL tables with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

I want to do like this:

```
 (Select field1
     FROM TB1
     INNER JOIN 
      .
      .
     WHERE etc
     ) temp1

INNER JOIN

(Select field1
     FROM TB2
     INNER JOIN 
      .
      .
     WHERE etc
     ) temp2

WHERE temp1.field1=temp2.field1
```

But i´m having an error: "Missing keyword"

What is missing here?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `union`

Comment: You need a `SELECT * FROM` at the top, before the first parenthesis as well as a `ON` condition for your `JOIN`. Replace your `WHERE` keyword with `ON`.

Comment: Quite a lot is missing actually.   What do you want your final results to be?   There is so much missing, that it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. But in general, a `JOIN` also needs a join condition defined by the `ON` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select from those two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (Select field1
      FROM TB1
      INNER JOIN 
      .
      .
      WHERE etc
     ) temp1
INNER JOIN (Select field1
            FROM TB2
            INNER JOIN 
            .
            .
            WHERE etc
           ) temp2 ON temp1.field1 = temp2.field1
```

I used `SELECT *`, but you can change it to list the fields that you want to return.

However, this gives you the results of your two queries combined in each row. If you want the results to add up vertically in different rows, then use `UNION` instead:

```
(Select field1
 FROM TB1
 INNER JOIN 
 .
 .
 WHERE etc)
UNION
(Select field1
 FROM TB2
 INNER JOIN 
 .
 .
 WHERE etc)
```

Comment: OK, already did. Thanks. Now i´m having the following error:       A parallel query server reached an exception condition. What this means? To many records?

Comment: Which query you used, the first with `JOIN` or the second with `UNION? You need to post your entire query, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Hi, where i can put the code. This comment field is limited.

Comment: Edit your question and add your query and all relevant info there. You can see an EDIT link under your question.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the sample you provided, you are actually trying to combine two tables, which is performed by `union`.

If you are really want to use `inner join`, in that case `on`  is missing. You need to provide a column to join those tables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html